# If I miss Sehri does it still count as a fast?

Tags: sawm

My alarm didn’t ring and I couldn’t wake up for Sehri (suhur). I woke up at 10 and realized that and had a cup of coffee and didn’t eat anything the whole day till aftar. Does it still counts as a fast?

Answer (score 1):

The matter of fast is simple, if you had in mind to fast the following day before you went to bed. You made an intention.
Eating or doing suhur has no relation to the validity of fast. It is only a recommended sunnah.

If you missed the suhur and woke up after fajr time you are not allowed to eat nor drink anything as else you would have broken your fast.
In the case you ate after fajr adhan there are two possibilities one is you did it intentionally (which is a big sin) or die to ignorance or unintentionally in the later case you may consider your fast as valid if you acted upon that once remembering that you you should fast and not eat or drink. Be aware that some madhhabs consider making up this day even in case of an unintentional breaking of fast as a due.

Note that there's a difference of rulings (and opinions too) between the obligatory fast as sich of Ramadan or making up days of Ramadan and optional fast in this matter.